# Trouble using individual ckrecords from array in swift function

Tags: ios, swift, function, cllocationmanager, cloudkit

I am trying to call the function addBoundry(CLLocation), but get the error "Type [CKRecord] has no subscript member". How can I call the function for each record individually.

```
func loadLocation(completion: (error:NSError?, records:[CKRecord]?) -> Void)
    {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil){
            (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error fetching locations: \(error)")
                completion(error: error, records: nil)
            } else {
                print("found locations: \(records)")
                completion(error: nil, records: records)
                for(var i = 0; i<records!.count; i += 1)
                {
                    addBoundry(records[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mistyped the error message in your question.

The error you were almost certainly actually getting was:

> `Type '[CKRecord]?' has no subscript members`

And the clue to your problem is in the error message. The `?` signifies that you have an array **Optional**, which in this case you need to unwrap.

```
guard let records = records else {
    // handle error in here
}
// after this point, `records` is a [CKRecord], not a [CKRecord]?
```

I would strongly suggest reading over the [Swift Programming Language documentation on Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Also, I assume you are using Swift 2.x, because Swift 3 gets rid of C-style for loops. And there's an easier way (in both version of Swift) to loop over the records:

```
for record in records {
    // do something with each record
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I convert the CKRecord back into a CLLocation @breakingobstacles

Comment: @Caleb: That would be a good candidate for a new question, since that's a different topic.